# How do I handle many duplicate pages created over the time for some valid reasons?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, landing-page

We have 6 years old website, we have created some pages for various reasons such as running a new campaign, trying new things and many other reasons for about last 6 years. Now, it looks like a duplicate page for Googlebot's eye and we are losing ranking and traffic.

Example pages created (just for an example):

- `mysite/buy-online-shoes.html` (Created to test some FB campaign in
  2012)
- `mysite/online-shoes-India.html` (created for some promotional
  offer in 2013)
- `mysite/online-shoes.html` (Created in 2014)
- `mysite/man-shoes-online` (Created in 2015)
- `mysite/men-shoes-online` (Created in 2016)
- `mysite/shoes-online`
- `mysite/shoes-India`

What is the best way to handle it? Mainly I am concerned about Google's organic traffic.

1. Should I simply delete all old pages & remove all internal links?
2. Should I keep only one page and remaining page do a (301 or 302 ?) redirection?
3. Just simply remove all internal links to my old pages, keep internal links only to new/current page?

What is the best approach or any other better approach is there?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `rel=canonical` and `rel=noindex`elements?

Comment: If they're exactly the same, could you use the old page for your current promotions? Or choose one page as the canonical version, and mark the older pages accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

The best answer would be determined by what do you want to do with all those sites. If I were the SEO of that site, I'll do the following:

1. Check organic traffic and keyword ranking for all those URLs.
2. If traffic/ranking is low, I'll use a `301 redirect` and keep only one of them.
3. If traffic/ranking is good for several URLs, I'll use redirect/canonical and keep alive two or three URLs.

For future actions, keep in mind that you should prevent those kind of URLs to be indexed, or at least, use [unavailable_after](https://googleblog.blogspot.com/2007/07/robots-exclusion-protocol-now-with-even.html%20unavailable_after) to remove them after the campaign/promotion is over.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Using 301 redirection is a good idea or using noindex is better ? I know there are 2 methods, Which is better to use, which will give better results in SEO ?

Comment: In this case (few URLs) I'll use a 301 redirect cause it's fastest and we want to transfer popularity and visitors to the canonical URL.

Answer (score 0):

Opt option 2, Keep one page that got more traffic than its duplicate pages and redirect (301) those duplicate pages to the main page that had more traffic.